# PropertyGrid: getting PropertyValueChanged notifications from a CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

The `PropertyGrid` control is very useful for editing objects at run-time. I'm using it as follows:

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Parent = this;
form.Text = "Editing MyMemberVariable";

PropertyGrid p = new PropertyGrid();
p.Parent = form;
p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
p.SelectedObject = _MyMemberVariable;
p.PropertyValueChanged += delegate(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs args) 
{ 
    _MyMemberVariable.Invalidate(); 
};

form.Show();
```

As you can see, I'm using the `PropertyValueChanged` notification to figure out when to update `_MyMemberVariable`. However, `_MyMemberVariable` is a class that I didn't write, and one of its members is a `Collection` type. The `PropertyGrid` calls the Collection Editor to edit this type. However, when the Collection Editor is closed, I do not get a `PropertyValueChanged` notification.

Obviously, I could work around this problem by using `ShowDialog()` and invalidating `_MyMemberVariable` after the dialog is closed.

But I'd like to actually get `PropertyValueChanged` events to fire when collections have been edited. Is there a way to do that without modifying `_MyMemberVariable` (I don't have access to its source code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't very elegant, but it solved the issue I was having when someone updates / changes the order of a collection from a property grid:

```
propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += (o, args) => PropertyGridValueChanged();
propertyGrid1.LostFocus += (sender, args) => PropertyGridValueChanged();
```

I listen to the `LostFocus` event when they click on something else.  For my particular use case this solution is sufficient. Thought I'd mention it in case someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and even reproduced the problem, however the solution I found won't help you, but I'm hoping the information may help another person help you.

Here goes

The problem is easily reproducable by creating a new windows form project, adding a property grid and a listbox to the form and setting the listbox as the property grid's selected object.

```
//designer code excluded
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = listBox1;

        propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += delegate(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalidate Me!");
        };

    }
}
```

When editing the items collection of the listbox, the event will never fire, the reason is because the Items property returns a reference to the collection. Since adding items to the collection doesn't actually change the reference when the property never appears to change so the property grid.

The solution I tried would be to extend property grid, and update the logic that compares the two and checks if the data in the collection has changed and call the event. I tried this but the PropertyGrid had an internal class PropertyGridView that caused problems for me.

I hope this helps someone else figure out your problem.

-jeremy